# Odac ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: c#, sql, odac, oraclecommand

I am writing a C# code that connects to ODAC. I think my query got no errors, but I get this error, I don't know how to solve.

This is my query

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ZAEDBA WHERE USER_ID = '" + login_id + 
                   "' AND APPID = '" + app_id + "' ;";
```

Can any one figure out what is wrong in here?

Comment: What is the error? (In passing, mandatory reference to [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).)

Comment: its in the title, this is my error ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: `login_id` and/or `app_id` probably contain characters that break (or abuse) your query. *Do not build queries this way. Use query parameters, not string concatenation.*

Comment: it seems that your sql don't have any errors. you could try getting text of comm.CommandText, and then try the query in sqldeveloper.

Comment: how i can make it parameter way? is it as sql? or odac has another method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is vulnerable for a security issue called [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)!

You should NEVER use string concatenation for building a query from strings (some SQL, some parameters)... Use always parameterized queries...

Sample code:

```
comm.BindByName = true;
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ZAEDBA WHERE USER_ID = :login_id AND APPID = :app_id";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue ("login_id", login_id);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue ("app_id", app_id);
```

Comment: i just want to see the data, then i will do it parameterized, i just want to check data right now, testing porposes

Comment: @X.L.Ant It gives the OP working code... and some hints on what is wrong with the current code (i.e. security problems)...

Comment: i will test it and come back to you

Comment: it didnt work, it gave me this error Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index -1 for this OracleParameterCollection with Count=0..

Answer (score 1):

Why there is a `;` in your sql command? Try this;

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ZAEDBA WHERE USER_ID = '" + login_id + "' AND APPID = '" + app_id "';
```

By the way, you should always use parameterized queries. This clearly open for an sql injection. For your query, use like this;

```
string commandText = "SELECT * FROM ZAEDBA WHERE USER_ID = @login_id " + AND
        + "WHERE APPID  = @app_id;";

command.Parameters.Add("@login_id", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@login_id"].Value = login_id;

command.Parameters.Add("@app_id", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@app_id"].Value = app_id;
```

Comment: no this is wrong, because in ODAC you will use : instead of @, and in the addwithvalue you should not add @

Comment: Yep, I assume these are type of `Int`, they used to be with `Add()` method also. Updated.